# NLog FindTargetByName Returning Null

Tags: .net, nlog

I'm using NLog 4.4.12 (latest version at time of writing) in a VB.NET 4.5 Visual Studio 2013 solution. When I try to retrieve a `MailTarget` in order to modify the configuration programmatically (eg, to set a user's server details, 'To' address, etc), I can do so using

```
Dim oTargets As ReadOnlyCollection(Of Targets.Target) = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets
```

This returns the two targets I have configured: a `DatatbaseTarget` (index = 0, Name = "Database_Target") and a `MailTarget` (index = 1, Name = "Email_Target").

But if I try to use

```
Dim oTarget as Targets.Target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("Email_Target")
```

or

```
Dim oTarget As Targets.MailTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName(Of Targets.MailTarget)("Email_Target")
```

or even

```
Dim oTarget as Targets.Target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName(oTargets(1).Name)
```

I get null.

I've searched for solutions in bug lists, GitHub and online generally and found nothing, so I'm probably doing something wrong. But I can't see what it is. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `LoggingConfiguration,FindTargetByName` will only currently only return targets that has been registered using `LoggingConfiguration.AddTarget`. But it could be nice if it was a little more userfriendly. Do your scenario work with this custom NLog.4.5.0-rc04 nuget-package: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nlog/nlog/build/4.5.0-beta7029/artifacts

Comment: Ugh! That's terrible!! But I was actually adding the target that way EXCEPT that I'd included a name in the add, eg `oConfig.AddTarget("Email", oTargetEmail)` which was over-riding the name in the actual target.

Comment: Will improve the internal logging around this, so one has a better chance to see why the config is not working. Guess it is safer to use the `AddTarget` without the name-parameter.

Answer (score 4):

As per Rolf's response, here's the issue in full. **NOTE**: this issue - or confusion - might well be fixed by the time you read this.

The problem was that I was creating `Targets` correctly and including a name value in their parameters, eg:

```
Dim oConfig As LoggingConfiguration = New LoggingConfiguration
Dim oMailTarget As New MailTarget
With oMailTarget
    .Name = "Email_Target"
    .SmtpServer = "mail.mydomain.com"
    .EnableSsl = True
    ...
oConfig.AddTarget("Email", oMailTarget)
```

But that last line, where I added `oMailTarget` with the optional name ("Email"), was probably overwriting the `oMailTarget.Name` value.

Changing that last line to simply:

```
oConfig.AddTarget(oMailTarget)
```

fixed the problem.

Were it me, I'd dump the `AddTarget(Name, Target)` overload so that if you want to name a `Target` it must be done in the `Target` object itself. Just my 2c.

Thanks to Rolf for his assistance.

Comment: Yes it is confusing that `AddTarget(Name, Target)` allows one to register a target with a different alias, than the actual name of the target. Not sure when this makes sense.

Comment: I can understand the idea of creating a `Target` as kind of a template - eg 'Database_Target' and then adding it as two different instances with different names, settings, etc. But I think you need to then remove the `.Name` property from the `Target` class. Or retain both, but as separate properties, eg `.Name` and `.InstanceName`. It's way to prone to error otherwise.

Comment: Yes one could have the restriction, that one could only perform AddTarget with alias, when the target was nameless. Then it would be less confusing. But right now it would be a breaking change, so it will have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem of `LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName` returning `null` for a valid logger (in C#), but (seemingly) for a slightly different reason. I was configuring logging like this (as per the documentation):

```
private static void ConfigureLogging()
{
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget() { FileName = "log.txt", Name = "logfile", Layout = "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" };
    var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget() { Name = "logconsole", Layout = "${message}" };
    var logmemory = new NLog.Targets.MemoryTarget () { Name = "logmemory", Layout = "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" };

    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, logconsole));
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logfile));
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logmemory));

    LogManager.Configuration = config;
}
```

This worked fine. But calls to `FindTargetByName` always returned `null`. I solved by explicitly adding targets:

```
private static void ConfigureLogging()
{
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget() { FileName = "log.txt", Name = "logfile", Layout = "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" };
    var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget() { Name = "logconsole", Layout = "${message}" };
    var logmemory = new NLog.Targets.MemoryTarget () { Name = "logmemory", Layout = "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" };

    config.AddTarget(logfile);
    config.AddTarget(logconsole);
    config.AddTarget(logmemory);

    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, logconsole));
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logfile));
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logmemory));

    LogManager.Configuration = config;
}
```